# Capture photo using photooutput, the size of the picture changes at random

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturephotooutput

Testing with iPhone XS, `sessionPreset` is set to photo. 
The picture resolution is usually 4032x3024, but sometimes it is taken at 3088x1938. What's the reason?

Below is my code.

```
let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings(format: [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)])
photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
photoSettings.flashMode = self.flashMode
self.photoOutput.capturePhoto(with: photoSettings, delegate: self)
```

Comment: What have you set your AVCaptureSession preset to?

Comment: i did set AVCaptureSession preset to .photo.

Comment: Your 3088x1938 images aren't from the front camera by any chance?

Comment: As you said, I got it from the front camera. Thank you.